# Adding test cases to TeamCity

Tags: unit-testing, testing, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have written some automated test cases in java (selenium IDE)for a project.The project is using `ruby on rails`. The project was configured in TeamCity. Now I am planning to add these test cases as a build step. How can I achieve this. Which build step should I use.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run them on your local machine?

If you run them from command line you can create build configuation with Command Line runner.If you run them by running JUnit test you can create a build configuration that runs JUnit tests (using some build tools like Ant, Maven, Gradle).